# How to start download a file after window.open(url, _blank)

Tags: javascript

what i need is:

- user click a link
- the download start automatically
- after 2 sec a new tab will open whit the URL of the Thank You page

Now, this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DownloadAndRedirect()
{
   var DownloadURL = "url-of-the-file";
   var RedirectURL = "url-of-thank-you-page";
   var RedirectPauseSeconds = 2;
   location.href = DownloadURL;
   setTimeout(DoTheRedirect(+RedirectURL+),parseInt(RedirectPauseSeconds*1000));
}
function DoTheRedirect(url) { window.location=url; }
</script>
```

Can you provide the correct code?
i know i can use window.open...but how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `setTimeout` correctly. You need to pass the `thanksyou` page url and set the seconds to `2000` which are equivalent to `2` seconds.

In `setTimeout` use `window.open` with a target `_blank` so that it opens in a new `tab`.

**Live Demo:** (Code tested and its working on localhost)

```js
function DownloadAndRedirect() {
  var DownloadURL = "https://www.google.com/";
  var RedirectURL = "https://www.google.com/";
  location.href = DownloadURL;
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.open(RedirectURL, '_blank')
  }, 2000)
}
DownloadAndRedirect()
```

Comment: @GiulioGualtieri happy to hear that. Happy coding :)